# What are the steps to factor $x^2 - 1$ into $(x+1)(x-1)$?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

Does $(x+1)(x-1) = x^2+1x-1x-1$? If so where are the $+1x$ and the $-1x$ when it is being factored from $x^2-1$ into $(x+1)(x-1)$?

What exactly are we dividing $x^2-1$ by to get $(x+1)(x-1)$ and how did you know what to divide it by?

Comment: You evaluate which values of $x$ makes the equation $x^2-1=0$ valid. These values are $x_1=1$ and $x_2=-1$. The corresponding *linear factors* are $(x-1)$ and $(x-(-1))=(x+1)$

Comment: Why are x subscript 1 and x subscript 2 different? What is the x in $x^2 to make the equation = 0?

Comment: $+1x-1x$, as you put it, equals zero. That's why it doesn't appear in the factored form.

Comment: "+1x-1x equal zero" I know, but do they show up anywhere during division. They come from the factoring by multiplication.

Comment: @Renoldus $x_1$ and $x_2$ are different values for $x$. They do not denote variables. Basically you have the equation $x^2-1=(x-x_1)\cdot (x-x_2) $ (linear factors). Here $x_1=1$ and $x_2=-1$ (roots).

Comment: You're labelling the figures on the right x (+1 and -1) in addition to the xs on the left. This is confusing.

Comment: Um  $+1x -1x = 0$.  So $(x+1)(x-1) = x^2 +1x -1x -1 = x^2 + 0 - 1 = x^2 -1$.

Comment: @Renoldus To whom is your comment addressed?

Comment: @callculus the last comment I made was addressed to you.

Comment: @Renoldus As I said: $x^2-1$ can be written as the product of two linear factors: $(x-x_1)\cdot (x-x_2)$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of $f(x)=x^2-1$. Thus the equation is $x^2-1=(x-x_1)\cdot (x-x_2)$. How to find the values for $x_1$ and $x_2$? Just evaluate the roots of $f(x)$. You can try some values for x or you can use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 0:

$+1x - 1x = 0$

So $(x+1)(x-1) = x^2 + 1x - 1x -1 =$

$x^2 +(1x-1x) -1 = $

$x^2 + 0 -1 =$

$x^2 -1 $.

Method 1:

$x^2 - 1 = $

$x^2 + x - x - 1 = $

$(x^2 +x) - (x+1) = $

$(x\cdot x + x\cdot 1) + (-1)\cdot(x+1) =$

$x\cdot(x + 1) + (-1)\cdot (x+1) =$

$\color{blue}x\cdot\color{red}{(x + 1)} + \color{blue}{(-1)}\color{red}{(x + 1)} = $

$(\color{blue}x + \color{blue}{(-1)})\color{red}{(x+1)} = $

$(\color{blue}x-\color{blue}1)\color{red}{(x+1)}$

Method 2:

$(x^2 - 1)\div (x+1) = ?????$

We need to find a firs term, $a$ so that when we multiply $a$ times $x+1$ and get $ax+a$ that $ax = x^2$. What can be $a$?  Well $ax=x^2$ and so (if we assume $x$ isn't always $0$) then $a= x$.

So $x(x+1) = x^2 + x$.

But $x^2 -1 \ne x^2 + x$ we must find a "remainder".

$(x^2 - 1)- (x^2 + x) = (x^2-x^2) + (-1-x) = -x - 1$.

So $x^2 - 1=  (x^2 + x) - x-1 = x(x+1) - x-1$.

And $(x^2 - 1)\div (x+1) = x + \frac {-x-1}{x+1}$

Now we must divide $x+1$ into $-x-1$.

We must find term $b$ so that when we multiply $b$ by $x+1$ and get $bx + b$ the first term $bx = -x$.  What can that $b$ be.  Clearly it is $b=-1$.

So $-1(x+1) = -x-1$.

And $-x-1$ *DOES* equal $-1(x+1)$ so we have no remainder.

So $(x^2 -1) = x(x+1) + (-1)(x+1)$.

And $(x^2 - 1)\div (x+1) = x + (-1) = x-1$

So $(x^2 - 1) \div (x+1) = x-1$ so that mean $(x^2-1)= (x-1)(x+1)$.

Method 3:

$(x^2 -1) = (x+a) (x+b)$

$= x^2 +ax +bx + ab =$

$x^2 + (a+b)x + ab$

And that is supposed to be $x^2 -1 = x^2 + 0*x + (-1)$.

So we need $a,b$ so that $a*b = -1$ and $a+b = 0$.

Okay so $ab = -1$ so $a = -\frac 1b$

And $-\frac 1b + b = 0$ so

$b = \frac 1b$ so

$b^2 = 1$.

So $b = \pm 1$.

And $a +b = a\pm 1 = 0$ so $a =\mp 1$.

So one of them is $1$ and the other is $-1$.

So $x^2 -1 = (x+a)(x+b) = (x+1)(x-1)$.

Method 4:

If $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has two solutions $x= m$ and $x = n$

Then $ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-m)(x+n)$.

So what are the two solutions to $x^2 -1 = 0$

They are:

$x^2 - 1 =0$ so

$x^2 = 1$ so

$x  = \pm 1$

So $m = 1$ and $n=-1$ are the two solutions and

so $x^2 -1 = (x- 1)(x-(-1)) = (x-1)(x+1)$.

........

But in *ALL* of these methods the $+1x -1x =0$ and the "cancel out".

You can cancel them to $0$ or pop them out of nowhere from $0$.

The this is you just have to think of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just what I needed. Though, how did you know you could go from x(x+1)+(-1)(x+1) to (x+(-1))(x+1)?

Comment: Distribution.   $Am + Bm = (A+B)m$.   In this case $A= x$ and $B=-1$ and $m = (x+1)$.  That's why put $x+1$ in red.

Comment: Why are you and all the answers saying $x^2-1$ needs to equal zero? Is this typical to solve for x?

Comment: I don't really see how x(x+1)+(-1) is the same as Am + Bm. That would be A(A+B)+(B)? I get the (A + B)m part, which is clearly (x+(-1))(x+1).

Comment: $x^2 -1$ doesn't need to equal zero and I *never* said it did. I said: *IF* $m$ and $n$ are solutions to $x^2 -1=0$ then $x^2-1 = (x-m)(x-n)$.  Obviously if $x \ne m$ and $x \ne n$ then $x^2 -1 \ne 0$....   It's is a fundamental theorem that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial.  And $P(m) = 0$ then $(x-m)$ will divide $P(x)$.  So if $P(x) = x^2 -1$ then $P(1) =0$ and $P(-1) = 0$ so $(x+1)$ and $(x-1)$ divides $x^2 -1$ and so $x^2 -1=(x+1)(x-1)$.

Comment: The equation is $x(x+1) + (-1)(x+1)$.  It is not $x(x+1) + (-1)$.  Any way.  If $\color{blue}{x=A}$ and $\color{green}{-1=B}$ and $\color{red}{x+1=m}$ then $\color{blue}x\color{red}{(x+1)} +\color{green}{(-1)}\color{red}{(x+1)} = \color{blue}A\color{red}m + \color{green}B\color{red}m=(\color{blue}A+\color{green}B)\color{red}m=(\color{blue}x + \color{green}{(-1)})(\color{red}{x+1})$.

Comment: Thank you for the color coding. That caused a light bulb to light over my head.

Comment: Towards the top of method 1 (again). How does $x^2+x - x-1$ become $(x^2+x) - (x+1)$? Why do parenthesis make the -1 a +1? I see that it works, but I'm missing how it changed.

Comment: Distribution again  $-(a+b) = (-1)\cdot (a+ b) = (-1)a + (-1)b = -a - b$.  And $-(a-b) = -a+b$.

Comment: I'd like to be able to say I got it and stop asking you, but, what was distributed? Are $a$ and $b$ just the x and 1 from the second, right half of the equation, $-x-1$, or $-(x+1)$?

Comment: $x+1$ was distributed.  $(x^2+x) = (x*x + x*1) = x(x+1)$ and $-x-1 = -1(x+1)$ so we have $x^2 + x - x -1 = (x^2 + x) + (-x-1)= x(x+1) + (-1)(x+1) = (x+(-1))(x+1)$.

Comment: I see. I thought distribution only pertained to multiplication and division. Though I can't say I have a really clear picture of why -x-1 becomes -(x+1), I do see that it works.

Comment: That *is* multiplication.  Multiplication by $-1$.   $-x - 1 = (-1)*x + (-1)*1 = (-1)*(x+1)= -(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y:=x-1$. Then

$$x^2-1=(y+1)^2-1=y^2+2y$$ which obviously factors as $$(y+2)y=(x+1)(x-1).$$

Answer (score 1):

We have the equation $f(x)=x^2-1=(x-x_1)\cdot (x-x_2)$, where $x_1,x_2$ are the roots of $f(x)$. Thus we have to find the solution of $x^2-1=0$. This is not difficult. Adding $1$ on both sides of the equation.

$x^2=1$

*square root*

$|x|=1$

Thus $x_1=\color{red}1$ and $x_2=\color{blue}{-1}$. Therefore

$$f(x)=x^2-1=(x-\color{red}1)\cdot (x-(\color{blue}{-1}))=(x-1)\cdot (x+1)$$

> I was thinking about square roots, but I knew the square root of -1
>   was a no no. The x with no subscript, x subscript 1, and x subscript 2
>   are still confusing me. Could you at least use a and b

You don´t calculate the square root of -1 here. You calculate the square root of $1$. And the equation $x^2=1$ has two solutions.

Sure you can use $a$ and $b$, where $a$ and $b$ are the roots of $f(x)$:

$f(x)=x^2-1=(x-a)\cdot (x-b)=0$. This is the representation of $f(x)$ with *linear factors* (!). Here we can use the **zero product property** which states: If at least one of the factors is $0$, then the product is $0$.

Then you solve $f(x)=x^2-1=0$  like above. After you´ve got the solution you can write the function with linear factors.

> "Adding 1 on both sides of the equation." I don't understand why this
>   needs to happen

If you solve an equation, it is always a good idea to separate the terms with the variable $x(,x^2,x^3,...)$ and the terms with out the variable $x$.

Comment: I was thinking about square roots, but I knew the square root of -1 was a no no. The x with no subscript, x subscript 1, and x subscript 2 are still confusing me. Could you at least use a and b?

Comment: "Adding 1 on both sides of the equation." I don't understand why this needs to happen.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2-1$ can take many values for different $x$.  $f(7) =48$ and $f(-3) = 9$.  But If $f(m) = 0$ then we say "$m$ is a root of $f(x)$" and "$m$ is a solution to $x^2-1=0$.  ... if is fundamental fact that a polynomial $x^2 +bx + c$ can have two roots and if $m$ and $n$ are the two roots then $x^2 + bx + c=(x-m)(x-n)$.  So if $x^2-1$ has two roots $m,n$ then $x^2 -1 =(x-m)(x-n)$.  So we must find the two solutions to $x^2 - 1=0$.To *SOLVE* that we add $1$ to both sides and get $x^2 = 1$.  So we must find the square root***s*** of $1$. We *don't* have to find the square roots of $-1$.

Comment: "Could you at least use a and b"  Numbers are numbers.  We can call them whatever the eff we like.  If we call them $x_1$ and $x_2$ or $a,b$ or $m,n$ or $Babar$ and $Celeste$ it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Renoldus I´ve made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you factor a polynomial, its roots must be roots of the factors. (If $p(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)$, $p(r)=0\iff f(r)=0\lor g(r)=0$.)

As

$$x^2-1=0\iff x=\pm1$$ there must be a factor that vanishes with $x=1$ and another  with $x=-1$.

Hence

$$x^2-1\propto (x-1)(x+1).$$

Comment: Why the 'proportional to' symbol instead of '='?

Comment: @Renoldus: because we are discussing zeroes, which leaves a free global coefficient ($x-1$ and $4x-4$ have the same root). Of course by multiplying the factors and matching the leading terms we will see that the coefficient will be $1$, but this is an additional step.